# How to perform HTTP PATCH with Domain Driven Design with strongly typed languages?

Tags: domain-driven-design

How can I perform an HTTP PATCH in a DDD application following the [RCF6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) JSON PATCH specification in a strongly typed language such as Java or C#. Conditions are not to violate DDD, have everything strongly-typed and have Entities be immutable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The intent of the `RFC6902` is not quite compatible with the `DDD` approach. This `RFC` is used to define a protocol used to mutate an object in a `CRUD` style, as opposed to `DDD` style. `DDD` focuses on the business behaviors using the ubiquitous language, whereas CRUD focuses on the data.

If you *really* want, you could use the `RFC6902` for the command side (aka the write side) of the application. Every `PATCH` request would map to one or more commands that will be send to a single aggregate identified by the `URL` of the Request. Also, only the `add` operation makes sense, as in `add and process a new command`. For some commands, the `remove` operation could make sense but this is even more weird.

So, a request could look like this:

```
PATCH /orders/1234/change/item/quantity HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Length: 326
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
   { "op": "add", "path": "/item/456", "value": 3 }
]
```

This request would set the `quantity` to `3` for the `item` with `id` equal to `456` in the `order` with `id` equal with `123`.

I repeat, `RFC6902` does not make sense for `DDD`.

Comment: I figured as much, but as I'm fairly new to DDD and I couldn't find any reference on the internet, I thought I'd ask. Thanks :)

Comment: I was with you in the first paragraph but then you lost me in the second. Using "add" for every operation is the same as not specifying an operation at all. I would use all the operations of the RFC and then map them to commands.

 `PATCH /orders/1234/item/456` with payload `[ { "op": "replace", "path": "/quantity", "value": 3 } ]
`