# DDD + CQRS pattern with multiple inherited Aggregate Roots

Tags: api, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs

*Disclaimer: I know that DDD/CQRS might not be a perfect choice for below use case, but it was working great so far for other tasks in the project and I want to stick with it for learning purposes (eg. learn the hard way where not to use it ;).*

Let's assume I'm building a Blogging Platform and have 3 types of posts: `LifestylePost`, `RecipePost` and `ReviewPost`. They have the same abstract base class `PostBase` which is an Aggregate Root and all of them share some properties like `Author` or implement methods like `Publish`, `Delete` etc. which change their `Status` and verify whether the state is valid. Each created post starts as a `Draft` which barely requires any validation, but switching to `Published` verifies nearly all properties.

Implementing commands/handlers like `PublishPost` or `DeletePost` was a breeze, but the problem starts when I'm thinking about `CreatePost` or `UpdatePost`. These are some dilemmas I'm currently facing:

1. **Create/update commands/handlers for each post types or one for all**

Having them separately for each post types gives me more control over the logic, allows to tailor each command model precisely, but makes my API more complex for the client. With the second option I can resolve the post type by some discriminator in the command and check whether all necessary properties for that particular type were provided.

2. **Create empty post draft first or already filled with the data**

When a user creates a new post (draft with an initial state) I can already call the API and add an empty post to the database, which would then be updated or I can wait until user inputs any data and clicks save. It's basically a matter of the arguments in the constructors of the posts.

3. **Handling post updates in general**

This is the point where I'm having the biggest issues now. Since there are quite many properties that could or could not be changed by the user, it's hard to split them to particular methods inside the Aggregate Root different than just `Update` with huge amount of nullable arguments where null would mean that the property has not been provided by the client and therefore not changed. Also adding `Status` property here would mean that the proper method for validating the state would have to be resolved. This solution somehow doesn't feel like a proper DDD design...

Which decisions would you make in each points and why?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Create/update commands/handlers for each post types or one for all**

Depends on whether the difference in post types has influence over the API or not. If your clients have differentiated interactions with your API depending on the post type, then I would have specific commands for each type. If your API is post type agnostic, then this is internal business concerns. You should then ensure that domain implementation is sufficiently different from type to type, because polymorphic domain is a lot more work than a simple "category" property.

2. **Create empty post draft first or already filled with the data**

Depends on whether knowing a user has started working on a draft has any value for your system. If it's like a personal blog, probably not. If you're writing software for a newspaper, then it could be insightful to anyone. Ask your domain experts.

3. **Handling post updates in general**

This is an interface design question rather than a business logic one in my opinion. If your users want to do a lot of small changes, you should consider providing PATCH routes in your API, with a standard like [JsonPatch](http://jsonpatch.com/). Depending on your implementation technology, you could benefit from libraries that does the object patching for you, saving a lot of code writing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So then it seems that the answer to 1st question depends a little bit on the 2nd one. If i decide to create an empty ``Post`` before user inputs any data, all types would have the same "entry point" in the domain and therefore could share the same command and only have different commands for updating (different properties that can be changed). The JsonPatch solution doesn't seem to work well with DDD: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658623/how-to-perform-http-patch-with-domain-driven-design-with-strongly-typed-language

Comment: If you have different endpoints for different post types, you can have type specific creation endpoints that will create the drafts accordingly. As said in the answer, if there is no specific behavior per post type, and you want easier post type change, then you should consider moving away from polymorphism.

Comment: Yes JsonPatch is much more CRUD oriented but your design is very CRUD oriented (CreatePost, UpdatePost, DeletePost). Especially UpdatePost is CRUD centric and has no business driver. If you want more DDD/microservice approach, then you should reconsider your modeling and splitting your post into smaller polysemic contexts.

Comment: You will also need to reconsider your API/UI design to be more process-centric and less data-centric. A blog platform is a very bad example for DDD, as data is the purpose of the application, rather then modeling a process.

Comment: I think you should be pragmatic about it, and accept the CRUD nature of the blog post content. This can still fit in a larger DDD/CQRS architecture, but don't over-engineer it. You'll waste time trying to fit a square in a triangle.

Comment: A more DDD approach makes sense if your are developing for a large blogging platform with different actors handling different parts of the publishing process : A creates the posts, B writes the text, C adds illustration, D links to relevant posts, etc ... Then you can split you UpdatePost into smaller, more business centered commands like SetPostIllustration

Comment: thanks a lot - that opened my eyes a lot on the proper use cases for DDD/CQRS. The above example I showed is also very simplified - in the real project domain validates the state of the ``Post`` for each change of the status within methods like ``Publish()``, ``Submit()`` etc. and also takes ``User`` (only a simplified model) as an argument to verify whether he/she has the required role (eg. only ``Administrator`` can Approve/Publish posts). For this DDD aproach was working great, but for the general post updates it is not anymore...

Comment: So if I had no choice and had to go for the DDD/CQRS - do you see any other idea than update commands per each type and general ``Update`` method with nullable arguments for each property that can be updated where null means not changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243236/discussion-between-arwynfr-and-toffik325).

Answer (score 1):

Is there really a difference in behaviour between the post types? Don't they all have `Draft()`, `Publish()`, `Cancel()` behaviours?

Given that inheritance means `X is a Y`, then you're basically saying they are all the same. This feels to me like a single `Post` aggregate with the possibility of a "PostType" value somewhere that might be part of an invariant (e.g. if you had a business rule that says "Review Posts cannot be published until a cooling-off period has elapsed).

This would mean a single set of application services to invoke those methods (and validate the invariants they implement).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right that they share some common behaviours and properties, but the difference between each ``Post`` is that they also have specific properties, eg. ``ReviewPost`` has some properties of the item being reviewed and also ``Rating``, ``RecipePost`` has a list of ``Ingredients``, ``CookingTime`` and so on. And because of that each type of the ``Post`` implements its own ``Validate()`` method, because for each of them the valid state while going public is a little bit different.